# CodeIgniter $_POST Not Working With REQUEST_URI protocol

Tags: codeigniter, post, uri

I have a simple login page and the URL structure is like www.mydomain.com/admin/auth

I had a problem several days ago where the $_POST had always been empty, so i googled and found http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/191918/ which suggested to change my config.php from:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

And finally it worked but only when i add index.php on the URL like this:
www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin/auth

I tried to make the $_POST work without having index.php on the URL but i couldn't figure it out. My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|user_guide|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

All i need to do is for the $_POST to work on my URL, is there any workout or workaround? Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
Here is my controller (i reduced so it only loads the view, for debugging)

```
public function index()
{
$this->load->view('admin/login');
}
```

And my view has been reduced to this:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

<html><head></head><body>       
<form method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='nama' value='test'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</body></html>
```

And this code works perfectly fine on a single file i made on my server without CI.

Comment: Could you post the HTML used in the login form & the PHP used to handle the request? If you are posting data to a url, there's no reason why $_POST will be empty

Comment: I edited and added the HTML and PHP used. When i add var_dump($_POST) whether i put it on view or on www.mydomain.com/index.php, it always return empty array.

Comment: Btw I think the change to the config is a red herring.  Post up the form you are using

Comment: I already posted up the form i am using, i was stuck for days and that was the last resort i had to try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out, it got something to do with my subdomain. When i disable the subdomain it all works fine, it seems to have something with the htaccess of subdomain and CI. Thank you for you time all :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the $_POST array through $this->input->post() ? For example:

```
$_POST['foo']
```

becomes

```
$this->input->post('foo')
```

Comment: Yes i have tried it, var_dump($this->input->post()) returns bool(false).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  print_r($this->input->post()); on the page you are posting to.